# Ideas for generating a specific pattern of random contours

Tags: matlab, geometry, computational-geometry, shapes, contour

I need to generate random shapes that are similar to the pattern of the white stripes in the image i am uploading.... 
[image]

Any ideas or algorithms on how to do this ?? The software I am going to use is matlab

Comment: No idea what you call "laminated contours", nor "adhere to the pattern". Can you show an example ?

Comment: edited the original question

Comment: Still very vague. The image looks like an Archimedean spiral that has been randomly perturbed, with perturbed thickness. Does matlab have a library for polygon manipulation ?

Comment: I do not know but if you could provide me with some code that plots the Archimedean spiral with the random pertubation I would find it extremely helpfull !!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral. You can perturb `theta` and/or `r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I decided to use the spiral suggested in the previous comments...

```
t = linspace(0,(rand()*4 +1)*pi,100);
k = rand()/2;
laminatedx = t.*cos(t) + k*rand(size(t));
laminatedy = t.*sin(t) + k*rand(size(t));
h = plot(laminatedx,laminatedy);
set(h,'linewidth',30);
set(h,'LineStyle','-.');
```